# Angular 2 Gulp Typescript Compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I've been following the angular 2 typescript [demo](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). I now want to use my own build pipeline using gulp. However, I'm getting typescript compilation errors when trying to use my compile gulp task. This is my project structure

```
- project
  |- app
    |- app.component.ts
    |- main.ts
  |- node-modules
  |- typings
  gulpfile.js
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
```

This is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('compile-app', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('./app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin'));
});
```

When I try and run 'gulp compile-app' I get the following errors

```
project/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
project/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
project/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
etc......
```

I cannot figure out what is going on. Any ideas?

node v6.2.1
npm v3.9.3
typings 1.0.5

Answer (score 2):

From your gulp errors it looks like you are missing ES6 features. If you changed your .tsconfig target attribute to "es6" it would compile, because Promise and Map have ES6 definitions. The problem with this approach is ES6 is still incompatible with most browsers. In order to use these and target ES5 you'll need the es6-shim.

With Typings ~1.0 and above you'll need to use:

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

Comment: Just tried with the target attribute set to "es6" and yest it compiled with no problems. However, tried installing typings `es6-shim`, `es6-promise` and `es6-collections` but continue to get the errors. You pointed me in the right direction, think I may have to start with a clean slate to nail this one - all got a bit confusing!

Comment: Agree, it's still a moving target to build to. I think angular 2 now uses core-js instead of es6-shim. From the QuickStart, these are the typings you need instead: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/typings.json.

Answer (score 0):

I can remove the build compilation errors by adding

```
///<reference path="../typings/index.d.ts/"/>
```

to the main entry point of the app, in this case `main.ts`, i.e., where I bootstrap the app. This will give typescript the correct references to the `core-js` typescript definitions installed by typings, i.e.,

```
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
```

and thus the shim definitions for es6 to work with es5 browsers.

**NOTE:** You do not need to install `es6-shim` with the latest release of angular (2.0.0-rc.2). Use core-js. If you add `es6-shim` and `core-js`, you'll get `duplicate identifier` error messages during the typescript compilation.